# present nested data in table using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Using angular 1.4.7

I have the following javascript object

```
var parents = [
    {"name" : "John", 
         childs:[{ "name" : "Child1", age:"4"},{"name" : "Child2",age:"8"}]},
    {"name" : "Peter", 
         childs:[{ "name" : "Child3", age:"5"},{"name" : "Child", age:"12"}]}
]
```

and I want to have the following output as html table

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Child1</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Child2</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Child3</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Child3</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have been trying using ng-repet-start to insert a new row (`</tr><tr>`) within the child loop.

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="parent in parents">
    <td >
        {{parent.name}}
    </td>
    <td ng-repeat-start="child in parent.childs">
        {{child.name}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{child.age}}
<!--new row within child loop and -->
</tr>
<tr>
     <td></td>
     <td ng-repeat-end></td>
<tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
```

The error I get in the console is:

> Unterminated attribute, found 'ng-repeat-start' but no matching 'ng-repeat-end' found.

If I take out the `</tr><tr>` I get no error, but also not the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will give you almost the output you've asked (some extra `<tbody>` tags there, but it's still valid `html`):

```
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="parent in parents">
      <tr ng-repeat="child in parent.childs">
        <td ng-if = "$index == 0">{{parent.name}}</td>
        <td ng-if = "$index != 0"></td>
        <td >
          {{child.name}}
        </td>
        <td>{{child.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is working [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/WLhcgg5DYNmn0K9Je41Z?p=preview)

I should say, that implementation is quite ugly. I would  used `<td rowspan="number_of children">` to achieve similar visual result. See implementation [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/43tM7H3TT4Bhy8qgcSEe?p=preview), with `rowspan` and a little bit of bootstrap.

```
<table class = "table table-condensed">
    <tbody ng-repeat="parent in parents">
      <tr ng-repeat="child in parent.childs">
        <td ng-if="$index == 0" rowspan="{{parent.childs.length}}">{{parent.name}}</td>
        <td>
          {{child.name}}
        </td>
        <td>{{child.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

**EDIT:** updated [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/43tM7H3TT4Bhy8qgcSEe?p=preview)

Dirty implementation for data with 'grandchildren'

```
$scope.withGrandChildren = [ 
{"name" : "John", 
  childs:[ 
    { "name" : "Child1", 
      age:"42", 
      grandchildrens:[
        {"name":"Graddchildren1_1", age:"12"} , 
        {"name":"Grandchildren1_2", age:"17"}
      ] 
    }, 
    { "name" : "Child2", 
      age:"38", 
      grandchildrens:[
        {"name":"Graddchildren2_1", age:"19"} 
      ] 
    } 
  ]
}, 
{"name" : "Peter", 
  childs:[
    { "name" : "Child3", age:"45"},
    {"name" : "Child", age:"12"}
  ]
} 
]
```

[image]

Comment: The answer solved my problem. How could I use this if there is another level of grandchildren?

Comment: Cool! Would you give an example of data, that you're going to use?

Comment: `var parents = [
    {"name" : "John", 
         childs:[
            { "name" : "Child1", age:"42", 
                grandchildrens:[{"name":"Graddchildren1_1", age:"12"} , {"name":"Grandchildren1_2", age:"17"}]
            },
            { "name" : "Child2", age:"38",
                grandchildrens:[{"name":"Graddchildren2_1", age:"19"} ]
            }
            ]},
    {"name" : "Peter", 
         childs:[{ "name" : "Child3", age:"45"},{"name" : "Child", age:"12"}]}
    ]`

Comment: See, updated answer... implementation does'n get 'prettier' :)

Comment: The updated link to Plunk es redirecting to the previous solution, not the one with the "grandchildren" solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="parent in parents">
    <tr ng-repeat="child in parent.childs">
        <td>{{parent.name}}</td>
        <td >
           {{child.name}}
        </td>
        <td>{{child.age}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The only difference of this with your desired output is that the `parent name` is displayed for all `child rows`